# How to use logical indexing and grepl to round specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I simply want to round off columns in a dataframe that match certains patterns. A bit like so but im running into problems with grepl.

```
group <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
var_ABC1 <- c(1.50, 2.60, 3.87, 4.00, 5.00, 6.08, 7.00, 9.00, 9.35, 50.00, 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00, 8.00, 9.00, 50.00)
var_GHI2 <- c(1.50, 2.60, 3.87, 4.00, 5.00, 6.08, 7.00, 9.00, 9.35, 50.00, 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00, 8.00, 9.00, 50.00)
var_DEF1 <- c(1.50, 2.60, 3.87, 4.00, 5.00, 6.08, 7.00, 9.00, 9.35, 50.00, 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00, 8.00, 9.00, 50.00)
df = data.frame(group, var_ABC1, var_GHI2, var_DEF1)


match <- c("var_ABC1", "var_GHI2")

idx <- grepl(match, names(df))
df[, idx] = round(df[, idx], 1)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `which()` and `paste0()` inside `grepl()` for matching in order to extract the position of variables:

```
#Data
group <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
var_ABC1 <- c(1.50, 2.60, 3.87, 4.00, 5.00, 6.08, 7.00, 9.00, 9.35, 50.00, 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00, 8.00, 9.00, 50.00)
var_GHI2 <- c(1.50, 2.60, 3.87, 4.00, 5.00, 6.08, 7.00, 9.00, 9.35, 50.00, 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00, 8.00, 9.00, 50.00)
var_DEF1 <- c(1.50, 2.60, 3.87, 4.00, 5.00, 6.08, 7.00, 9.00, 9.35, 50.00, 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00, 8.00, 9.00, 50.00)
df = data.frame(group, var_ABC1, var_GHI2, var_DEF1)
#Vector
match <- c("var_ABC1", "var_GHI2")
#Match
idx <- which(grepl(paste0(match,collapse = '|'), names(df)))
df[, idx] = round(df[, idx], 1)
```

Output:

```
df
   group var_ABC1 var_GHI2 var_DEF1
1      A      1.5      1.5     1.50
2      A      2.6      2.6     2.60
3      A      3.9      3.9     3.87
4      A      4.0      4.0     4.00
5      A      5.0      5.0     5.00
6      A      6.1      6.1     6.08
7      A      7.0      7.0     7.00
8      A      9.0      9.0     9.00
9      A      9.3      9.3     9.35
10     A     50.0     50.0    50.00
11     B      1.0      1.0     1.00
12     B      2.0      2.0     2.00
13     B      3.0      3.0     3.00
14     B      4.0      4.0     4.00
15     B      5.0      5.0     5.00
16     B      6.0      6.0     6.00
17     B      7.0      7.0     7.00
18     B      8.0      8.0     8.00
19     B      9.0      9.0     9.00
20     B     50.0     50.0    50.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `match` has exact column names - you don't need `grep` or anything else. You can use column names directly within `[`:

```
df[match] = round(df[match], 1)
df
#    group var_ABC1 var_GHI2 var_DEF1
# 1      A      1.5      1.5     1.50
# 2      A      2.6      2.6     2.60
# 3      A      3.9      3.9     3.87
# 4      A      4.0      4.0     4.00
# ...
```

`grep` and regular expressions are good for when you are looking **within** strings for patterns, or when you have a general pattern with wildcards. When you have an exact match, you can use `%in%` or `==` just like with numbers.